# Saving NetCDF with grid_mapping ValueError

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to save clipped NetCDF by shapefile. I've tried use any relevant parameter or drop crs variable (`drop_vars`), however without success.

Here is my snippet:

```
import rioxarray as rxr
import rasterio as rio
import xarray as xr    


xds = xr.open_dataset(file.nc)
geodf = gpd.read_file(shape.shp)
xds.rio.write_crs("EPSG:4326", inplace=True)
clipped = xds.rio.clip(geodf.geometry.apply(mapping), geodf.crs)
clipped.to_netcdf("test.nc")

out:
ValueError: failed to prevent overwriting existing key grid_mapping in attrs. This is 
probably an encoding field used by xarray to describe how a variable is serialized. To 
proceed, remove this key from the variable's attributes manually.
```

However `rioxarray` function saving the dataset to GeoTiff is working well.

```
clipped.rio.to_raster("file.tif", driver="GTiff")
```

Many thanks for any suggestion on how to proceed.

PS: There is no time dimension only Lat/Lon and Variables - NDVI

Comment: Have you tried doing this "To proceed, remove this key from the variable's attributes manually."?

Comment: @RobertWilson This is CRS? Yes, I've tried to drop it...

Comment: I think the problem might be "grid_mapping". Can you write after dropping that attr, e.g. with `del clipped.attrs['grid_mapping']`?

Comment: This looks related - https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/3739 - seems there can be issues when setting attrs which are used by xarray (or rioxarray) for encoding

Comment: @MichaelDelgado KeyError: 'grid_mapping'

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Yes I find it too :-) However, I am not working with the time dimension so I am confused :-/

Comment: Well I think that issue may be relevant, but to the spatial coordinates you're using and the grid_mapping attribute. Can you try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by creating a version of xdf and geodf in code, or at least print out the dataset and variable attrs so we can understand the problem a bit more?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I will try it during the weekend. Sorry lot of work.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I solved it by dropping the `grid_mapping` attribute that is created when you write the CRS.

This worked for me. Let's see `xr_df` is my `xarray` dataset:

```
vars_list = list(xr_df.data_vars)  
    for var in vars_list:  
        del xr_df[var].attrs['grid_mapping']
```